# About the usage of Memory in a linux server

Tags: memory, top

I find my server's memory usage is so high, part of the output of command free is shown below:

```
          total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:      82446460   81961412     485048          0     152820   77580400
-/+ buffers/cache:    4228192   78218268
Swap:     83841020     200108   83640912
```

You see, it used almost all of my memory.

However, I can't the process which consumes a lot of memory. The following is the output of command `top` which is sorted by `M`.

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
18434 cloud     20   0 19.5g 754m  11m S    0  0.9  13:14.90 jsvc
15420 root      20   0 25.0g 506m  16m S    0  0.6   4:14.67 jsvc
15826 root      20   0 5125m 344m 6896 S    1  0.4   7:37.66 kvm
24435 root      20   0 5229m 299m 6868 S    0  0.4   0:49.09 kvm
16993 root      20   0 4507m 277m 6944 S    0  0.3  27:20.54 kvm
23789 root      20   0 4401m 147m 6896 S    0  0.2   0:28.46 kvm
 2057 mysql     20   0 1435m  96m 8208 S    0  0.1  11:37.82 mysqld
15130 root      20   0  812m 7276 3408 S    0  0.0   1:25.45 libvirtd
24993 root      20   0 21832 4396 1720 S    0  0.0   0:00.26 bash
```

I think the memory consumed by processes is less than 3% in total. So, I wonder where my memory goes?

Comment: The rest is probably used witin the kernel. Have you looked at `/proc/meminfo`?

Comment: see also http://linuxatemyram.com

Comment: I don't like answer of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14102/real-memory-usage, it's abstract and never answer the point.

Comment: I like the answer of linuxatemyram.com!