# Reliably determine free memory in BSD

Tags: freebsd, memory, top, bsd

Linux distributions tend (but are [not required](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_5.0.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/command.html)) to include `free` from [procps](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/), which allows a nice concise display of memory consumption:

```bsh
# free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7688        5027         180         827        2479        1589
Swap:          8189        2082        6106
```

In order to approximate this in BSD, I've tried a number of different items, but they all give me different answers (presumably because they have different contexts?).  For example:

```bsh
# sysctl -a |grep Memory
Virtual Memory:             (Total: 1077397132K, Active 3458308K)
Real Memory:                (Total: 1171952K Active 975744K)
Shared Virtual Memory:      (Total: 56264K Active: 38652K)
Shared Real Memory: (Total: 22184K Active: 19700K)
Free Memory Pages:  1664588K

# sysctl hw |awk '/mem:/ { printf "%s %.0fM\n", $1, $2/1024^2 }'
hw.physmem: 32756M
hw.usermem: 29102M
hw.realmem: 33792M

# grep memory /var/run/dmesg.boot
usable memory = 34346901504 (32755 MB)
avail memory  = 33139134464 (31603 MB)

# top |grep -Em2 '^(Mem|Swap):'
Mem: 980M Active, 25G Inact, 3654M Wired, 948M Cache, 3285M Buf, 678M Free
Swap: 9216M Total, 363M Used, 8853M Free, 3% Inuse
```

I'm not the first person to have this inquiry; almost 7y ago, it was [posted](https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-questions/2010-August/220432.html) to the FreeBSD-questions list and a perl script was [proposed](https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=149844) out of it, offering [freebsd-memory.pl](https://people.freebsd.org/~rse/dist/freebsd-memory) <sup><sub>(output was narrowed to fit here)</sub></sup>:

```bsh
# perl freebsd-memory.pl
SYSTEM MEMORY INFORMATION:
mem_wire:       3831771136 (  3654MB) [ 11%] Wired: disabled for paging out
mem_active:  +  1028284416 (   980MB) [  3%] Active: recently referenced
mem_inactive:+ 26741092352 ( 25502MB) [ 80%] Inactive: recently not referenced
mem_cache:   +   993902592 (   947MB) [  2%] Cached: almost avail. for allocation
mem_free:    +   710340608 (   677MB) [  2%] Free: fully available for allocation
mem_gap_vm:  +      995328 (     0MB) [  0%] Memory gap: UNKNOWN
-------------- ----------- ---------- ------
mem_all:     = 33306386432 ( 31763MB) [100%] Total real memory managed
mem_gap_sys: +  1040515072 (   992MB)        Memory gap: Kernel?!
-------------- ----------- ----------
mem_phys:    = 34346901504 ( 32755MB)        Total real memory available
mem_gap_hw:  +    12836864 (    12MB)        Memory gap: Segment Mappings?!
-------------- ----------- ----------
mem_hw:      = 34359738368 ( 32768MB)        Total real memory installed

SYSTEM MEMORY SUMMARY:
mem_used:       5914402816 (  5640MB) [ 17%] Logically used memory
mem_avail:   + 28445335552 ( 27127MB) [ 82%] Logically available memory
-------------- ----------- ---------- ------
mem_total:   = 34359738368 ( 32768MB) [100%] Logically total memory
```

*Update from [forquare's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/349890/reliably-determine-free-memory/349922#349922)* – yet another method:

```bsh
# vmstat -h
 procs      memory      page                    disks     faults         cpu
 r b w     avm    fre   flt  re  pi  po    fr  sr da0 da1   in   sy   cs us sy id
 0 2 0   3372M  1627M    39  32   0   0     8  23   0   0   23   25   38 19  9 71

# swapinfo -h
Device          1K-blocks     Used    Avail Capacity
/dev/da0s1b       9437184     363M     8.6G     4%
```

I ran all seven of the above BSD commands (sysctl two ways, /var/run/dmesg.boot, top, freebsd-memory.pl, vmstat, swapinfo) on a single command line, so the output should be pretty consistent, yet I see a lot of conflicting values.

**Which of these is "most accurate?"**  I want a small script (no compilation!) that can be run on pretty much any system (or else just BSD) that concisely display my memory consumption the way procps free does.

I'm using `top |grep -Em2 '^(Mem|Swap):'` at the moment.

Side note 1: [Freecolor](https://chiselapp.com/user/rkeene/repository/freecolor) is almost exactly what I want, but it require compilation and it has a dependency that I don't want to deal with (I'm not the maintainer of these systems), but it may help visitors looking at this question.

Side note 2: The procps (Linux) `top` command doesn't play well with pipes.  You can make it faster with `top -d.1 -n1`, but it might make your cursor vanish.

Comment: This related question may provide some clues to the differences but not an answer to this question: [What do the different memory counters in FreeBSD mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134862/what-do-the-different-memory-counters-in-freebsd-mean)

Comment: Why don't you want a compiled program?

Comment: Too many architectures and too many systems that I use too briefly to justify compiling this (plus its dependencies) for each one, and I don't have control of the deployment mechanisms (I'm not maintaining these systems).  I want a drop-in script, ideally brief enough to fit in my .bashrc and .zshrc.

Answer (score 3):

For simple free/active figures, I've always used `vmstat`:

```
~ # vmstat
procs  memory       page                    disks     faults         cpu
r b w  avm   fre   flt  re  pi  po    fr   sr da0 cd0   in    sy    cs us sy id
1 0 2 841M   89M    23   0   0   0    29    9   0   0    4   110    93  0  0 100
```

From the man page:

> Information about the usage of virtual and real memory.  Virtual
>                pages (reported in units of 1024 bytes) are considered active if
>                they belong to processes which are running or have run in the
>                last 20 seconds.
>
> ```
>          avm     active virtual pages
>          fre     size of the free list
> ```

For information on swap usage:

```
~ # swapinfo -h
Device          1K-blocks     Used    Avail Capacity
/dev/da0p2        2097152      25M     2.0G     1%
```

Comment: Okay, so that's yet another set of memory metrics that don't quite line up with the rest.  I've added it to the list in the question.  My question is which one should I trust and why?

Comment: The `vmstat` command here doesn't list the total physical memory of the system and I'm seriously questioning its values; I have a system with 16G of hw.realmem that `vmstat -h` says has 2.1G active and 350M free (`top` says it has 318M free plus 12G Inact, so maybe I want that latter value, which presumably means "inactive"?)

Comment: You might find value reading [How does FreeBSD allocate memory?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/234446/how-does-freebsd-allocate-memory) It gives insight into how the memory actually is allocated and you might better understand what you want.