# FD column of `lsof` shows DEL in some cases, instead of an FD number

Tags: lsof

1. What does this mean?
2. How does `lsof` find such FDs?  I.e. compared to normal FDs, which can be found easily like `ls -l /proc/$PID/fd/$FD`.

---

```
$ lsof -p $(pgrep pulseaudio) | head -n1
COMMAND     PID       USER   FD      TYPE             DEVICE  SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME

$ lsof -p $(pgrep pulseaudio) | grep DEL
pulseaudi 25911 alan-sysop  DEL       REG                0,5           2334404 /memfd:pulseaudio
pulseaudi 25911 alan-sysop  DEL       REG                0,5           2340448 /memfd:pulseaudio
pulseaudi 25911 alan-sysop  DEL       REG                0,5           2335426 /memfd:pulseaudio
pulseaudi 25911 alan-sysop  DEL       REG                0,5           2340018 /memfd:pulseaudio
pulseaudi 25911 alan-sysop  DEL       REG                0,5           2340021 /memfd:pulseaudio
pulseaudi 25911 alan-sysop  DEL       REG                0,5           2334322 /memfd:pulseaudio
pulseaudi 25911 alan-sysop  DEL       REG                0,5           2336421 /memfd:pulseaudio
```

`man lsof` only documents a `DEL` value for the `TYPE` column, not the `FD` column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `lsof` usually reports entries from the Linux `/proc/<PID>/maps` file with `mem` in the <del>TYPE</del> FD column.  However, when `lsof` can't `stat(2)` a path in the process `maps` file and the `maps` file entry contains `(deleted)`, indicating the file was deleted after it had been opened, `lsof` reports the file as `DEL`.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37160579/1601027, as pointed out by @don_crissti.

---

`lsof` cannot show the size of these files, even when run as root.  (My `lsof` is version 4.89).

However, if you have both a new enough kernel and `root` access, you can both see the maps in `ls -l /proc/$PID/map_files/`, and you can run `stat --dereference` on individual files to show their size.  This could be used to inspect the resources used by "deleted" mapped files.  In particular `memfd`s, which never appear in the filesystem and are always considered as `(deleted)` files.

```
$ ls -l /proc/$(pgrep pulseaudio)/map_files | head
total 0
lr--------. 1 alan-sysop alan-sysop 64 Mar 18 23:50 562004ac5000-562004ada000 -> /usr/bin/pulseaudio
lr--------. 1 alan-sysop alan-sysop 64 Mar 18 23:50 562004cda000-562004cdb000 -> /usr/bin/pulseaudio
lr--------. 1 alan-sysop alan-sysop 64 Mar 18 23:50 562004cdb000-562004cdc000 -> /usr/bin/pulseaudio
lrw-------. 1 alan-sysop alan-sysop 64 Mar 18 23:50 7fab98000000-7fab9c000000 -> /memfd:pulseaudio (deleted)
lrw-------. 1 alan-sysop alan-sysop 64 Mar 18 23:50 7fab9c000000-7faba0000000 -> /memfd:pulseaudio (deleted)
lrw-------. 1 alan-sysop alan-sysop 64 Mar 18 23:50 7faba0000000-7faba4000000 -> /memfd:pulseaudio (deleted)
lrw-------. 1 alan-sysop alan-sysop 64 Mar 18 23:50 7faba4000000-7faba8000000 -> /memfd:pulseaudio (deleted)
lrw-------. 1 alan-sysop alan-sysop 64 Mar 18 23:50 7faba8000000-7fabac000000 -> /memfd:pulseaudio (deleted)
lrw-------. 1 alan-sysop alan-sysop 64 Mar 18 23:50 7fabac000000-7fabb0000000 -> /memfd:pulseaudio (deleted)

$ sudo stat --dereference /proc/$(pgrep pulseaudio)/map_files/7fab98000000-7fab9c000000
  File: /proc/25911/map_files/7fab98000000-7fab9c000000
  Size: 67108864    Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 5h/5d   Inode: 2399078     Links: 0
Access: (0777/-rwxrwxrwx)  Uid: ( 1000/alan-sysop)   Gid: ( 1000/alan-sysop)
Context: unconfined_u:object_r:user_tmp_t:s0
Access: 2018-03-18 23:47:48.714061694 +0000
Modify: 2018-03-18 23:47:48.713061683 +0000
Change: 2018-03-18 23:47:48.713061683 +0000
 Birth: -
```

E.g. at least it was possible to see that no individual memfd, at least held directly by an FD or by a memory mapping, was consuming gigabytes on its own.  It would still be nice to have some better tooling or scripts around this though.

```
$ sudo du -aLh /proc/*/map_files/ /proc/*/fd/ | sort -h | tail
du: cannot access '/proc/self/fd/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/thread-self/fd/3': No such file or directory
108M    /proc/10397/map_files/7f1e141b4000-7f1e1ad84000
111M    /proc/14862/map_files/
112M    /proc/10397/map_files/
113M    /proc/18324/map_files/7efdda2fb000-7efddaafb000
121M    /proc/18324/map_files/7efdea2fb000-7efdeaafb000
129M    /proc/18324/map_files/7efdc82fb000-7efdc8afb000
129M    /proc/18324/map_files/7efdd42fb000-7efdd4afb000
129M    /proc/18324/map_files/7efde52fb000-7efde5afb000
221M    /proc/26350/map_files/
3.9G    /proc/18324/map_files/

$ ps -x -q 18324
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
18324 pts/1    S+     0:00 journalctl -b -f

$ ps -x -q 26350
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
26350 ?        Sl     4:35 /usr/lib64/firefox/firefox

$ sudo ls -l /proc/18324/map_files/7efde52fb000-7efde5afb000
lr--------. 1 root root 64 Mar 19 00:32 /proc/18324/map_files/7efde52fb000-7efde5afb000
-> /var/log/journal/f211872a957d411a9315fd911006ef03/user-1001@c3f024d4b01f4531b9b69e0876e42af8-00000000002e2acf-00055bbea4d9059d.journal
```