# Why does systemd *not* have `/dev/dri/...` open?

Tags: systemd, logind

Right now my system is doing disk IO when I switch from a text console on tty6 to GNOME on tty3.  1.4GB of swap is in use.

On tty6, I ran `sudo lsof -p 1 | grep dev`, to check if it was a similar issue to "[What could be using 6GB of my swap?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/431982/what-could-be-using-6gb-of-my-swap)".  Based on the background information there, I would expect PID 1 to have open file descriptors for `/dev/dri/...`.  But it didn't have any!

The same is true when I ran the command from tty3. The output is different though, as it now includes open file descriptors for `/dev/input/...`.

These results are repeatable, if I switch back to tty3 and try again etc.

**N.B. This is code that I have touched in upstream systemd, so it could well be my fault :-).**  Looking at the systemd git commit messages for `src/login`, I can't find a clear deliberate change in this behaviour.

I have a VM for each of Fedora 27 and Fedora 28. <del>They</del> Fedora 27 looks ok when I boot them and run `lsof` on the serial console. However, on the Fedora 28 VM, if I run `chvt 6`, then the same problem shows up.

---

EDIT: this apparent regression goes away if I set SELinux to "permissive" (policy violations are logged, but allowed).  I've submitted it as an issue in Fedora.  [SELinux interferes with systemd-logind restart code](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1577498)

---

- systemd-238-7.fc28.1.x86_64 (<del>should include the fix for "[What could be using 6GB of my swap?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/431982/what-could-be-using-6gb-of-my-swap)"</del>)
- gnome-shell-3.28.1-3.fc28.x86_64

This does not happen on the Fedora 27 VM with

- systemd-234-10.git5f8984e.fc27.x86_64
- gnome-shell-3.26.2-5.fc27.x86_64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the VT switch caused gnome-shell to release input devices (ReleaseDevice method in logind dbus API). This causes logind to remove the FD for the device.

So this is most likely affected by the issue [#8344](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/8344) "session_device_free(sd) also drops all *other* device fds of that session" .  A fix is merged for systemd v239.

I confirmed this by testing a pre-release version of systemd, which included the fix.

> ... to check if it was a similar issue to "What could be using 6GB of my swap?"

Quite possibly. The fix for that is also merged for v239, and hence not present in `systemd-238-7.fc28.1.x86_64`.